# Separate marshaller per node in Apache Ignite

Tags: java, caching, ignite, distribute

The way Apache Ignite allows to configure the WAL location and WAL archive location, is it possible to configure the marshaller location as well?

I suspect that there is slowness due to all the nodes using the same marshaller, and I was wondering if there is a way to configure the marshaller such that each node uses a different marshaller.

From a basic search and investigation of the code, I do not believe it is, but it would be great help if someone could point out how it could be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

As you already mentioned it's possible to change WAL path. It's described [here](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/persistence/native-persistence#configuration-properties). If you take a glance at the 'Default Value' column of the table you'll spot the `IGNITE_HOME` variable. You can try to play with it. More details could be found in the [guide](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start/java#installing-ignite). After that the variable will be respected by the bundled scripts (like `ignite.sh`). Something like that:

```sh
export IGNITE_HOME = path_to_a_node_files
```

Answer (score 0):

You may set `IgniteConfiguration.workDirectory` property to the desired location.